# Python - turning text column into array, where I can access each number in the array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have a text file containing multiple columns. I can successfully print all the items in the 2 columns I am interested in by using this code:

```
with open(file) as catalog:
    for line in catalog:
        column = line.split()
        if not line.startswith('#'): #skipping column labels
            x = float(column[3])
            y = float(column[4])
```

Now if I add a print(x) command inside the 'if not' loop, it prints all of the x values. But if I put print(x) outside of the loop it only prints the last item. What I want is to be able to access the full array of x and y values anywhere in my code. I also need to be able to access the x/y array items individually, so I can say x[2], and it will give me the third value in the x array. I can not get this part to work even inside of the 'if not' loop. Thanks for any help, I have only been using Python for a couple of weeks..

Comment: do you want the x and y values together?

Comment: no, separate. the answers below did what I wanted

Comment: just out of curiosity, does anyone know why I got downvoted for my question? I'd hate to get my account suspended, and I thought I formatted correctly..

Comment: thanks, anything specifically you recommend for future posts? Thinking I could add some of the things I tried (even though most of them were probably way off)

Comment: Just a tip: Move the `column = line.split()` inside the `if not` block. The way it is now, you're wasting time splitting lines that you then discard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your Xs and Ys in a list:

```
X_list = []
Y_list = []
with open(file) as catalog:
    for line in catalog:
        column = line.split()
        if not line.startswith('#'): #skipping column labels
            x = float(column[3])
            y = float(column[4])
            X_list.append(x)
            Y_list.append(y)
#then print the lists if you wish
print(X_list)
print(Y_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you'll need to build a list of values.

```
with open(file) as catalog:
    x_values = []
    y_values = []
    for line in catalog:
        column = line.split()
        if not line.startswith('#'): #skipping column labels
            x_values.append(float(column[3]))
            y_values.append(float(column[4]))
```